# Add content on Magento search result pages

Tags: magento

What is the best method for adding content or merchandising on search result pages?

For instance, I have this URL:
http://beta.www.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=cookies

I need to add a javascript snippet or other HTML to display an ad banner about milk here. 
How would I do that without much programming? 
Is there an extension that can be added to allow for this capability?

Thanks,

Brad

Answer (score 0):

simply edit or create this file

```
/www/app/design/frontend/[template]/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

in your template.